# After upload, image thumbnail not displaying

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

My dropzone js is not showing image preview after the upload.
My js code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
            maxFiles: 5,
            createImageThumbnails: true,
            acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
            uploadMultiple: true,
            init: function() {
                this.on("addedfile", function(file) {});
            }
        };
```

Also,I have changed css for the preview path (if that's the case), still no luck.
Please help.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the webconsole? Have you spelled everything correctly (Lower case and Uppercase at the right position)?

Comment: You can take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032132/dropzone-image-upload-options-not-working . This user had also a problem with dropzone like you